# How to display last URL in UIWebView after the app has been terminated 2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have tried this code but cant get it to work. Thanks in advance.

```
(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
 (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] saveObject:
   [[request URL] absoluteString] forKey: @"SAVED-URL"];
}
```

Comment: It should have worked.. Have you tried taking the log or get the value from UserDefaults?

Comment: After you've saved it, what's the code for using it?

Comment: Well this is all I have so far I am new to saving data. So do you know what I should do? Thanks